# When we extend an allauth view and create a new url based on that view is the old "/accounts/*" URLs of django allauth still required?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I extended the SignupView of django-allauth and created a url "/account-signup/" and also some minor changes in the template and I'm using the url name of my url. So, it keeps showing error that:

NoReverseMatch at /account-signup/
Reverse for 'account_login' not found. 'account_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I've tried searching where the url name account_login is used in the template. Also, I've tried enabling the default URLs given by django allauth. It doesnt show error when the allauth URLs are included in the urls.py file.

/signup.html

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<p>some content from sugat</p>

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'my_app:custom_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

/my_app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import *

app_name = "my_app"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account-signup/$', AccountSignUp.as_view(), name="account_signup"),
]
```

/myproject/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'', include("my_app.urls")),
]
```

Comment: have you tried using `my_app:account_signup`?

Comment: yes, it shows that same error